# How can I use the same wifi interface in AP mode and station mode simultaneously?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, routing, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I am trying to use a single wifi interface on a YOCTO Linux device to create an access point and to connect to an existing wifi simultaneously. The AP is successfully created and clients can connect to it and receive an IP. However, when the same interface is use to connect to a wifi, the AP clients get disconnected and if they  try to reconnect, they cannot receive an IP.

Here is what I'm doing to generate the AP:

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type __ap
ifconfig wlan1 192.168.3.1 up
udhcpd /etc/udhcpd.conf
hostapd /etc/myhostapd.conf
```

Here is the content of hostapd configuration:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

ssid=myssid
hw_mode=g
channel=11
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypasswd
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

udhcpd configuration:

```
start 192.168.3.10
end   192.168.3.100

interface   wlan1
```

I connect to a wifi using wpa_supplicant:

```
wpa_supplicant -c wpa.conf -i wlan0 -B
udhcpc -i wlan0
```

According to `iw phy0 info`, the interface is able to do both things simultaneously:

```
Wiphy phy0
        max # scan SSIDs: 10
        max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
        max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
        max # match sets: 16
        max # scan plans: 1
        max scan plan interval: 508
        max scan plan iterations: 0
        Retry short limit: 7
        Retry long limit: 4
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports roaming.
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x1020
                        HT20
                        Static SM Power Save
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        No RX STBC
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
                        * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Supported commands:
                 * new_interface
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * start_ap
                 * set_bss
                 * join_ibss
                 * set_pmksa
                 * del_pmksa
                 * flush_pmksa
                 * remain_on_channel
                 * frame
                 * set_wiphy_netns
                 * set_channel
                 * start_sched_scan
                 * start_p2p_device
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
                 * crit_protocol_start
                 * crit_protocol_stop
                 * update_connect_params
        Supported TX frame types:
                 * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * managed: 0x40 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
        software interface modes (can always be added):
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 3, #channels <= 2
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
                   total <= 4, #channels <= 1
        Device supports scan flush.
        Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
        Supported extended features:
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_PSK ]: 4-way handshake with PSK in station mode
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_1X ]: 4-way handshake with 802.1X in station mode
```

I tried to delete the wlan0 interface and to create two new ones (one in station mode and one in ap mode) but I got an error:

```
iw dev wlan0 del
```

> command failed: Unknown error 524 (-524)

UPDATE: when wpa_supplicant is run, clients that are connected to the AP get kicked out. If they try to reconnect, udhcpd hangs on OFFER message.

Comment: Is your hostapd configured to run on the same channel as the existing network you want to connect to (note the `#channels <= 1` restriction)?

Comment: Yes. I really think it's a DHCP problem: when wpa_supplicant is called, clients get kicked out but they can reconnect to the AP. The problem is that they cannot receive their IP back. udhcp keeps printing "sending OFFER to..." but nothing happens